# How can ı create responsive background-image?

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to try the background-image feature, but somehow the picture
width: 1350px; I can't fit the container part, even if I fit it, it is not responsive. When the screen shrinks, the parts of the photo do not disappear. I want it to be as small as the screen and fit into the container. What is the solution to this problem?

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.image{
  max-width: 1350px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1350px;
  height: 600px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
  width: 420px;
  height: 100%;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn-black {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.9rem;
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.btn-black i {
  margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.box-1 .btn-black span {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/berkay.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:768px)" href="css/tablet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:500px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://orangestate.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Facebook-Post-Landscape-Banners-Travel-07.png);">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box box-1">
          <a class="btn-black" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <span>GÖRÜNTÜLÜ KONUŞMA</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <a class="btn-black" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <span>EMLAKÇILARIMIZ</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <a class="btn-black" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <span>EVLERİMİZ</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box box-4">
          <a class="btn-black" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <span>ŞUBELERİMİZ</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
.image {background-size: contain;}
```

That should solve it.

Edit: Not "*.img*"

Comment: 375 X 812 The screen view is very small like this https://hizliresim.com/Mgnu55, and it does not take up 1350px in normal size.

Comment: btw., it is not good style to work with background-pictures. Instead create a container, place a div inside for the image and place a div as overlay. This is much more convenient and solves many problems. Example: https://addin.online/de

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 provides class `img-fluid`. For doing so, you can try this:

```
<div class="image img-fluid"
        style="background-image: url(https://orangestate.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Facebook-Post-Landscape-Banners-Travel-07.png);">
       
   <!-- your code inside -->

</div>
```

For your `.image`, change it into this:

```
.image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the container is 1350px, but the photo takes up 100% of the screen, and the photo still gets smaller when the screen gets smaller.

Answer (score 0):

```
.image{
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;

}
```